# Why is SwiftUI onTapGuesture{} modifier not triggered on a rotated rectangle

Tags: swiftui, shapes

If I create a rectangle of say 100 wide and 20 high and then rotate it 90 degrees the onTapGuesture{} modifier does not get called if I click on the rectangle near the top or bottom.

It seems that the contentShape() may not correspond with the rotated rectangle

```
let fixView = Rectangle()
            .rotation(self.fixture.currentAngle)
            .fill(self.fixture.color)
            .overlay(Rectangle().rotation(self.fixture.currentAngle).stroke(self.fixture.borderColor, lineWidth: self.fixture.borderWidth).frame(width: overlayWidth, height: overlayHeight))
            .frame(width: width, height: height)
            .position(x: x, y: y )

            .onTapGesture {
                GlobalData.shared.selectedFixture = self.fixture.object
        }
```

I find the same think happens with .onHover{} - it is just triggered when the mouse is over the shapes frame rectangle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `rotation` does not change original layout frame which accepts gestures, so you have to do this explicitly using `.contentShape`, like below

```
Rectangle()
    .rotation(self.fixture.currentAngle)
    .fill(self.fixture.color)
    .overlay(Rectangle().rotation(self.fixture.currentAngle).stroke(self.fixture.borderColor, lineWidth: self.fixture.borderWidth).frame(width: overlayWidth, height: overlayHeight))
    .frame(width: width, height: height)
    // << here !! NB to not put this line after .position()
    .contentShape(Rectangle().rotation(self.fixture.currentAngle))  
    .position(x: x, y: y )

    .onTapGesture {
        GlobalData.shared.selectedFixture = self.fixture.object
}
```

Tested with Xcode 11.4 / iOS 13.4

Note: pay attention that hittesting works only for opaque parts (just in case some of your colors are clear)

Comment: Not working for me.  Note that there are a number of shapes in a ZStack  - if I add contentShape() then it seems the top shape in the view is always selected regardless of where I click on the container view

Comment: Fixed - I moved the 'contentShape()' modified to before the '.position()' modifier.  The '.position()' modifier returns a rectangle the size of the parent.

Comment: how can I get onHover{} to work on the Shape - it seems to ignore the contentShape()

Comment: @DuncanGroenewald, I experimented with onHover, but did not manage to work it at all. So, can't say anything for now.